# perform segue collection view inside a tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have UICollectionview that embedded into a UITableView.
now I want to perform a segue to a new ViewController when user has clicked on a cell

import UIKit

class productsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
var imgArr = [
    UIImage(named: "1000008614"),
    UIImage(named: "1000008621"),
    UIImage(named: "1000008629")
]

var imgName = [
    "iPhone XS",
    "iPhone XS Max",
    "iPhone 11"
]

var imgPrice = [
    "15,000,000 T",
    "17,000,000 T",
    "21,000,000 T"
]

@IBOutlet weak var btnShowAll: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lblSectionName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ProductsCollectionVIew: UICollectionView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    ProductsCollectionVIew.delegate = self
    ProductsCollectionVIew.dataSource = self
    ProductsCollectionVIew.reloadData()
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imgArr.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Products", for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionViewCell

    cell.imgProduct.image = imgArr[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblProductName.text = imgName[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblPrice.text = imgPrice[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //here I can't use self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self)
}
@IBAction func btnShowAllAction(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

}

I couldn't perform segue to a new view controller 
please help me.
thanks

Comment: What does it mean "I couldn't perform segue"? Is there any error message or something? Can you provide some sample project i.e. on github?

Comment: at didSelectitemAt function when I use performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: self) it say that " Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue' "

Comment: Did you give segue identifire ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't user `performSegue()` in `UITableViewCell` subclass, because this method is available only in `UIViewController`s.

There is simple solution for your problem - you can add "callback" to cell and fill this callback in view controller.

Your cell:

```
class ProductsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var didSelectItemAction: ((IndexPath) -> Void)?

    //...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        didSelectItemAction?(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Code in view controller:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath)
        guard let productsCell = cell as? ProductsTableViewCell else {
            return cell
        }

        productsCell.didSelectItemAction = { [weak self] indexPath in
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourID", sender: self)
        }

        return productsCell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are Having an Warning from the given above code you can simply do this:

```
let Tablecell = MyTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCellID, for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

        Tablecell.configureCell() // this is function which setups my collection view

        let collectionCell = Tablecell

        collectionCell.didSelectItemAction = { [weak self] indexPath in

                self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueID", sender: self)
            }

            return collectionCell
        }
```